# Displaying guessed letter in hangman program?

Tags: java

I want to be able to displayed a guessed letter once it is guessed in my hangman program. So for example if the word is hello it will be displayed to the player as  so is h is guessed by the player it will say yes as it does but then display the string h*** does anyone know how I can achieve this? Here is my code:

Hangman class:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package hangman;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Adam2_000
 */
public class Hangman {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String player = "";
        String selection;
        int turn = 12;
        List<String> wordBox = new ArrayList<String>();
        boolean hangman = false;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //New instances of class and arrays
        words words = new words();
        String easyWords1[] = words.easyWords;
        String mediumWords1[] = words.mediumWords;
        String hardWords1[] = words.hardWords;
        Random random = new Random();


        System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman version 1");
        System.out.println("Please choose a difficulty");
        System.out.println("A: Easy");
        System.out.println("B: Medium");
        System.out.println("C: Hard");

        System.out.println(" _________     ");
        System.out.println("|         |    ");
        System.out.println("|         0    ");
        System.out.println("|        /|\\  ");
        System.out.println("|        / \\  ");
        System.out.println("|              ");
        System.out.println("|              ");


        char iChoice;

        do {
            selection = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        } while (selection.isEmpty());
        iChoice = selection.charAt(0);
        if (iChoice != 'X') {
            switch (iChoice) {

                case 'A':
                    System.out.println("You have choosen easy:");
                    //Get and print random string from easyWords                   
                    int selectA = random.nextInt(easyWords1.length);
                    String replaceAllEasy = easyWords1[selectA].replaceAll("\\S", "*");
                    // Print the randomly selected word and its length
                    System.out.println("Random String selected: " + replaceAllEasy);
                    System.out.println("This word contains " + easyWords1[selectA].length() + " letters");

                    //while hangman == false continue to ask player for letters
                    while (hangman == false) {
                        System.out.println("Turns remaining: " + turn);
                        System.out.println("Please choose a letter A-Z :");
                        String easyChosenLetter = scan.next();

                        if (wordBox.contains(easyChosenLetter)) {
                            System.out.println("Letter alreay choosen please choose another letter");
                        } else {
                            wordBox.add(easyChosenLetter);
                        }

                        if (easyWords1[selectA].contains(easyChosenLetter)) {

                            System.out.println("Wordbox letters are: " + wordBox);
                            System.out.println("Yes!");
                            turn--;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Wordbox letters are: " + wordBox);
                            System.out.println("No!");
                            turn--;
                        }

                        if (turn == 0) {
                            hangman = true;
                        }

                        while (hangman == true) {
                            System.out.println("You lose!");
                            System.exit(0);
                        }

                        //unstarredString = "Bee", you can do unstarredString.substring(0,1) + oldstr.substring(1,2)
                    }
                    break;

                case 'B':
                    System.out.println("You have choosen Medium");
                    //Get and print random string from mediumWords
                    int selectB = random.nextInt(mediumWords1.length);
                    String replaceAllMedium = mediumWords1[selectB].replaceAll("\\S", "*");
                    // Print the randomly selected word and its length
                    System.out.println("Random String selected: " + replaceAllMedium);
                    System.out.println("This word contains " + mediumWords1[selectB].length() + " letters");

                    //while hangman == false continue to ask player for letters
                    while (hangman == false) {
                        System.out.println("Turns remaining: " + turn);
                        System.out.println("Please choose a letter A-Z :");
                        String mediumChosenLetter = scan.next();

                        if (wordBox.contains(mediumChosenLetter)) {
                            System.out.println("Letter alreay choosen please choose another letter");
                        } else {
                            wordBox.add(mediumChosenLetter);
                        }

                        wordBox.add(mediumChosenLetter);
                        if (easyWords1[selectB].contains(mediumChosenLetter)) {
                            System.out.println("Wordbox letters are: " + wordBox);
                            System.out.print("Yes!");
                            turn--;

                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Wordbox letters are: " + wordBox);
                            System.out.println("No!");
                            turn--;
                        }

                        if (turn == 0) {
                            hangman = true;
                        }

                        while (hangman == true) {
                            System.out.println("You lose!");
                            System.exit(0);
                        }

                    }
                    break;

                case 'C':
                    System.out.println("You have choosen Hard");
                    //Get and print random string from hardWords
                    int selectC = random.nextInt(hardWords1.length);
                    String replaceAllHard = hardWords1[selectC].replaceAll("\\S", "*");
                    // Print the randomly selected word and its length  
                    System.out.println("Random String selected: " + replaceAllHard);
                    System.out.println("This word contains " + hardWords1[selectC].length() + " letters");

                    //while hangman == false continue to ask player for letters
                    while (hangman == false) {
                        System.out.println("Turns remaining: " + turn);
                        System.out.println("Please choose a letter A-Z :");
                        String hardChosenLetter = scan.next();

                        if (wordBox.contains(hardChosenLetter)) {
                            System.out.println("Letter alreay choosen please choose another letter");
                        } else {
                            wordBox.add(hardChosenLetter);
                        }

                        wordBox.add(hardChosenLetter);
                        if (easyWords1[selectC].contains(hardChosenLetter)) {
                            System.out.println("Wordbox letters are: " + wordBox);
                            System.out.print("Yes!");
                            turn--;

                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Wordbox letters are: " + wordBox);
                            System.out.println("No!");
                            turn--;
                        }

                        if (turn == 0) {
                            hangman = true;
                        }

                        while (hangman == true) {
                            System.out.println("You lose!");
                            System.exit(0);
                        }


                    }
                    break;



            }

        }
    }
}
```

Words class:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package hangman;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author Adam2_000
 */
public class Words extends Hangman {

    String[] easyWords = {"Bee", "Car", "Fish", "Shed"};
    String[] mediumWords = {"House", "Sheep", "Castle", "Phone"};
    String[] hardWords = {"Octagon", "Crocodile", "Chocolate", "Motorbike"};

    public String[] getEasyWords() {
        return easyWords;
    }

    public void setEasyWords(String[] easyWords) {
        this.easyWords = easyWords;
    }

    public String[] getMediumWords() {
        return mediumWords;
    }

    public void setMediumWords(String[] mediumWords) {
        this.mediumWords = mediumWords;
    }

    public String[] getHardWords() {
        return hardWords;
    }

    public void setHardWords(String[] hardWords) {
        this.hardWords = hardWords;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "words{" + "easyWords=" + easyWords + ", mediumWords=" + mediumWords + ", hardWords=" + hardWords + '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148281/mask-string-with-characters which has a version for masking chars in hangman like games

Comment: I used that to get my string to display with the *'s but I can't see how to use it to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would like to recommend that you split the Hangman code into two files. Ex.

Hangman.java

```
package hangman;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Adam2_000
 */
public class Hangman {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String selection;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        /*
         *  I moved the variables found here to the Game class 
         */

        //New instances of class and arrays
        Words words = new Words();


        System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman version 1");
        System.out.println("Please choose a difficulty");
        System.out.println("A: Easy");
        System.out.println("B: Medium");
        System.out.println("C: Hard");
        System.out.println("X: Exit");      // Just for user friendlyness

        System.out.println(" _________     ");
        System.out.println("|         |    ");
        System.out.println("|         0    ");
        System.out.println("|        /|\\  ");
        System.out.println("|        / \\  ");
        System.out.println("|              ");
        System.out.println("|              ");

        char iChoice;

        do {
            selection = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        } while (selection.isEmpty());

        iChoice = selection.charAt(0);
        if (iChoice != 'X') {
            switch (iChoice) {
                case 'A':
                    System.out.println("You have chosen easy:");
                    new Game(words.easyWords, scan);                //All three levels can be called from the same class with the same code.
                    break;                                          //This will help reduce amount of code, and help when you need to change all three at once.

                case 'B':
                    System.out.println("You have chosen Medium");
                    new Game(words.mediumWords, scan);              //Called with the String[] of words you want to use and the scanner to save memory.
                    break;

                case 'C':
                    System.out.println("You have chosen Hard");
                    new Game(words.hardWords, scan);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Game.java

```
    package hangman;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {
    String player = "";
    int turn = 12;
    List<String> wordBox = new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean hangman = false;
    Scanner scan;
    Random random = new Random();

    String letters;     // For displaying letters
    String mask;        // For character Mask

    public Game(String[] words, Scanner scanner){
        scan = scanner;

        int selectA = random.nextInt(words.length);

        letters = words[selectA];               //Load word into String for display. This just makes the code more readable.        
        mask = letters.replaceAll("\\S", "*");  // Mask the words

        System.out.println("Random String selected: " + mask);
        System.out.println("This word contains " + letters.length() + " letters");

        while (hangman == false) {
            System.out.println("Turns remaining: " + turn);
            System.out.println("Please choose a letter A-Z :");
            String ChosenLetter = scan.next();

            if (wordBox.contains(ChosenLetter)) {
                System.out.println("Letter already chosen please choose another letter");
            } else {
                wordBox.add(ChosenLetter);
            }

            if (letters.contains(ChosenLetter)) {
                char[] cLetters = letters.toCharArray();    //Load letters and mask to char array for editing
                char[] cMask = mask.toCharArray();

                for(int i=0; i < cMask.length; i++){
                    if(cLetters[i] == ChosenLetter.charAt(0)){
                        cMask[i] = cLetters[i];
                    }
                }

                mask = new String(cMask);   //Load new mask into String

                System.out.println("Wordbox letters are: " + wordBox);
                System.out.println("Yes!" + mask);                      // Prints mask after Yes!

                turn--;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wordbox letters are: " + wordBox);
                System.out.println("No!" + mask);                               //Prints mask after No!
                turn--;
            }

            if (turn == 0) {
                hangman = true;
            }

            while (hangman == true) {
                System.out.println("You lose!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next I would like to show you how i answered your question.

In the above code you will see that I have loaded the word into some variables named `mask` and `letters`. I then used those variables in this piece of code

```
 char[] cLetters = letters.toCharArray();//Load letters and mask to char array for editing
 char[] cMask = mask.toCharArray();

 for(int i=0; i < cMask.length; i++){
      if(cLetters[i] == ChosenLetter.charAt(0)){
          cMask[i] = cLetters[i];
      }
  }

  mask = new String(cMask); //Load new mask into String

  System.out.println("Wordbox letters are: " + wordBox);
  System.out.println("Yes!" + mask);                        // Prints mask after Yes!
```

and for the no
`System.out.println("No!" + mask);`

I hope that this is helpful. And nice job with the code. I love how you setup the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do this for each level.  Basically, its relying on `indexOf` to find the position of the character within the word and replace it.

```
            if (easyWords1[selectC].contains(hardChosenLetter)) {
                String word = easyWords1[selectC];
                char[] unMasked = replaceAllHard.toCharArray();
                unMasked[word.indexOf(hardChosenLetter)] = hardChosenLetter.charAt(0);
                replaceAllHard = new String(unMasked);
                System.out.println("Wordbox letters are: " + wordBox);
                System.out.print("Yes!");
                System.out.println(replaceAllHard);
                turn--;

            } else {
                System.out.println("Wordbox letters are: " + wordBox);
                System.out.println("No!");
                turn--;
            }
```