# Masking the centre part of the email ID

Tags: java, regex, masking

I want to mask the email id as follows :

```
Input                   |   Output
qwerty@gmail.com        : qw**ty@gmail.com
helloworld@gmail.com    : he******ld@gmail.com
stackoverflow@gmail.com : st*********ow@gmail.com
abcde@gmail.com         : ab*de@gmail.com
abcd@gmail.com          : a**d@gmail.com
abc@gmail.com           : a*c@gmail.com
ab@gmail.com            : a*@gmail.com
```

1. Max 2 characters at both the extremes if available,  minimum 1 character at each end are to be displayed or just mask the last character.
2. The string has to be atleast 2 characters in length (ab@gmail.com).

I referred some of the solutions provided, but was not able to achieve the second and third scenario using those. Is there a possibility to find a fix ? I'm not well versed with regex, so I'm not sure which way to go ahead.

references :
[masking of email address in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33100298/masking-of-email-address-in-java)

[How to i mask all string characters except for the last 4 characters in Java using parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58361766/how-to-i-mask-all-string-characters-except-for-the-last-4-characters-in-java-usi)

Comment: [Here's](https://ideone.com/khzI3K) an IDEOne example showing one way to do it.  Not saying it's the best/most efficient, just first thing that came to mind.  Not putting as an answer, as I didn't do it with regex at all :/.

Comment: Could you please put some more, longer examples to refine the requirement of "centre"? (That is, email id of length 7,8,9,10) Also, do you require a regex or will another solution work?

Comment: @MichaelEaster: I have added some more examples, maybe that would help ?

Comment: With the newly added examples, you can ignore my solution above.  This assumed you wanted to evenly split '\*'s and non-'\*' components for any length.

Comment: Just curious what should happen with email address a@example.com

Comment: How should it be done for `abcd@gmail.com` and `abcde@gmail.com`?

Comment: Have made some edits, to clarify further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting reads regarding what can, and what can not be in an E-Mail Address would be [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2049510/4725875) and [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2071250/4725875) especially if you want to utilize [Regular Expressions](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html).

Here is another method to accomplish the task at hand:

```
public static String maskEMailAddress(String emailAddy) {
    String id = emailAddy.substring(0, emailAddy.lastIndexOf("@"));
    String domain = emailAddy.substring(emailAddy.lastIndexOf("@"));
    if (id.length() <= 1) { 
        return emailAddy;
    }
    switch (id.length()) {
        case 2:
            id = id.substring(0,1) + "*";
            break;
        case 3:
            id = id.substring(0,1) + "*" + id.substring(2);
            break;
        case 4:
            id = id.substring(0,1) + "**" + id.substring(3);
            break;
        default:
            String masks = String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(id.length() - 4, "*"));
            id = id.substring(0,2) + masks + id.substring(id.length() - 2);
            break;
    }

    String address = id + domain;
    return address;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code is located [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/gists/tree/master/java/egg_StackOverflow_63995240)

Consider a method that replaces a regex within an input string (credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20999446/12704)):

```
String replace(String regex, String replacement, String input) {
    String result = "N/A";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
    if (m.find()) {
        int groupToReplace = 1;
        result = new StringBuilder(input).replace(m.start(groupToReplace),
                                                  m.end(groupToReplace),
                                                  replacement).toString();
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("internal error");
    }

    return result;
}
```

then the various cases can be isolated into client code. Here, we assume that the "email id" has been stripped from the email address. (e.g. `qwerty` is `input` and not `qwerty@gmail.com`). Code snippet:

```
// TODO: the regex strings can be compiled into proper Pattern objects
if (numChars == 2) {
    regex = ".(.)";
    replacement = ASTERISK;
} else if (numChars == 3) {
    regex = ".(.).";
    replacement = ASTERISK;
} else if (numChars == 4) {
    regex = ".(..).";
    replacement = ASTERISK + ASTERISK;
} else {
    regex = "..(.*)..";
    int numAsterisks = numChars - 4;

    // requires JDK 11+
    replacement = ASTERISK.repeat(numAsterisks);
}

String result = replace(regex, replacement, input);
```

Above, note that `String.repeat` was introduced in JDK 11.

This is neither efficient nor elegant but is somewhat readable (esp. if unit-tested thoroughly). It has a simplistic treatment of what constitutes an email address.

Another solution, which doesn't use regular expressions, is included [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/gists/tree/master/java/egg_StackOverflow_63995240).

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative regex:**

```
"(?:(\\w{2})(\\w+)(\\w{2}@.*)|(\\w)(\\w{1,2})(\\w@.*)|(\\w)(\\w)(@.*))"
```

**Regex in context:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "qwerty@gmail.com\n"
            + "helloworld@gmail.com\n"
            + "stackoverflow@gmail.com\n"
            + "abcde@gmail.com\n"
            + "abcd@gmail.com\n"
            + "abc@gmail.com\n"
            + "ab@gmail.com";

    // 9 matcher group in total
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:(\\w{2})(\\w+)(\\w{2}@.*)|(\\w)(\\w{1,2})(\\w@.*)|(\\w)(\\w)(@.*))");
    List<Integer> groupIndex = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    for (String email : str.split("\n")) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        if(matcher.find()) {
            List<Integer> activeGroupIndex = groupIndex.stream()
                    .filter(i -> matcher.group(i) != null)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            String prefix = matcher.group(activeGroupIndex.get(0));
            String middle = matcher.group(activeGroupIndex.get(1));
            String suffix = matcher.group(activeGroupIndex.get(2));
            System.out.printf("%s%s%s%n", prefix, "*".repeat(middle.length()), suffix);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
qw**ty@gmail.com
he******ld@gmail.com
st*********ow@gmail.com
ab*de@gmail.com
a**d@gmail.com
a*c@gmail.com
a*@gmail.com
```

**Note:** "String   repeat​(int count)" only works from Java 11 and up.